# programatically creating django zinnia blog entries for non-admin users

Tags: django, blogs

For a website that is using django zinnia blog, I need the possibility to, beyond authors using the admin to create articles, to have a limited way for non-admin users to create blog entries, in their own specific area, with limited functionality (e.g. preset category, all entries start as draft etc..)

Now I was wondering if I could just create an own small ui for it and create Entries programatically in a django view (not in admin)... (with authors in those cases being non-admin users) ...

Is there any reason why this would be a very bad idea, or is this something that would really break things in Zinnia ?

Thanks in advance

Cheers

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

I've done one part of this a few months ago. The client found the admin interface too complicated and wanted something simpler. I created view/templates that allowed users to add/edit blog entries -  There were no major issues.

That said, this was still for admin users - there may be permission issues or hidden assumptions in zinnia that users are admins. I doubt there would be much trouble overcoming them - it's a nicely written app with decent interfaces.

I can show you some code if you're interested.

Comment: Yes please, if there is some code sample that you don't mind sharing that would be very much appreciated. Depending on size I assume you can post them here, or email me at thomas.remmmert@gmail.com ?

Comment: I'd like to see an example of zinnia can you e-mail me code to at klanestrotalisman@gmail.com